# Getting data from related records

Tags: php, database-design, yii

When linking data in different tables together using foreign ids, I often end up writing inelegant code to get the information I need.  Here is an example:

Say I have a table Message, with the following fields:

```
id, touserId, fromuserId, title, message
```

touserId and fromuserId refer to the id of the User objects that are sending and receiving the message respectively.

Say I want to show all the messages sent to a particular user.  I end up writing something like this in my view - which I know is bad!

```
<?
$messages=Message::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("touserId"=>Yii::app()->user->userid));
foreach ($messages as $message) {   
$fromuser=User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("id"=>$message->fromId));
?>
<div>
<h4><?=$message->title;?></h4>
<p>From: <?=$fromuser->name'?>
<p><?$message->body;?></p>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Is there a more elegant way to access the information from related records (in this case the name of the user sending the message?)

Comment: First things first, I would move that into the controller, and pass the array from the controller to the view.  Does your model not contain the fromuser relation to the fromuser name?

Comment: I guess what I mean is there a way of doing something like $message->fromId->name . And Yii knows to go and get the name from the other table?

Comment: You can modify your model and add a relationship: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Message model, you can do this:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'name' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'User', 'fromuserId')
    )
}
```

Alternatively, you could modify your model to include a JOIN so you get the user names.

Comment: Great.  I'll get this set up.  But there's no way to easily hook in all the attributes of the linked model?  The user in this case.